# How to deploy react and node.js (express) project in Hostinger Shared without buying VPS package?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, deployment

1

I bought a hosting and a domain in hostinger, then I started to develop an application with react, nodejs, ] and Express and at the time of doing the deploy I realized that hostinger does not support node js unless I buy a vps which at this time I can not afford.

I read some where that I can use the subdomain for the server, but I didn't know how.

My mistake was not to look at the details of hostinger, I bought it without having noticed.

The application is simple, it consists of a blog where there is a login, add, delete and update posts. Is there a way to make it compatible with node js or some solution for this?

A solution that can allow me to host my site on hostinger

I have deployed my project, but only the frontend part of my project worked ; which is the landing page. In the other hand the part of the page that is supposed to display the details of the cars retrieved from mongo db didn't work.